# How to prevent genymotion rotate back after app exit

Tags: android, genymotion

I use genymotion 2.6.0 for Android development, my app is always in landscape mode. The problem is, when the app launch, the emulator rotate to landscape, but when the app exit, and the emulator show home screen, it will auto rotate back to portrait mode. It happens to all apps that support landscape model, Settings, Contacts etc.

I tried with different virtual devices, all the same.

How can I prevent it rotate back? In another word, how to keep the emulator in landscape mode?

Comment: A lot of devices don't allow landscape mode on the home screen. Genymotion being a device specific emulator, likely replicates that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As @zgc7009 told, the screnn position depends on the application running foreground.
On Android **phones**, the launcher app does not support landscape and that's why the window rotates back to portrait. If you open again your application, the windows will be back on landscape mode.

On the next version of Genymotion we will change this behavior and the window will keep its position whatever the app is running.